# iOS Google Maps: Draw images along a polyline?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-polyline

Using the Google Maps SDK for iOS (latest version), I'm trying to figure out some way to display images along a polyline on the map.  I don't want the images to zoom in/out with the map, but I do want them to rotate with it -- the images are of various types of arrows, which need to be pointing in the direction of the route.

Is this something anyone knows how to do fairly straightforwardly?

Comment: There is google directions API which returns the all points (lat, lng) where the route turns https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Also have a look at. this https://github.com/varshylmobile/MapManager its in swift

Comment: @QadirHussain that sounds like something I could work with... Thanks for the pointers.